# Recursively traverse dictionary trie to count total words

Tags: c++, trie

I've built a trie from a linked list. Each node contains a char and an array of 27 nodes (letters of the alphabet + an extra spot for $ to represent the end of a word). 
I tried writing a recursive method to count the number of words but it is returning 1. I'm not sure how to fix it or exactly what is wrong.

```
int recursiveCount(Node* temp, int count)
{
    if (temp->value == '$')
    {
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (temp->array[i] != NULL)
        {
            return recursiveCount(temp->arr[i],count);
        }
    }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `count` by value which means that it goes out of scope when the recursion unravels and only the one "furthest" out gets returned and since that i s the first `count` to be incremented it is just 1. Pass by reference instead `int recursiveCount(Node* temp, int& temp);`

Comment: I don't quite understand why it goes out of scope. The variable "count" gets incremented and then I return the current value of "count" to the next call of the function. I understand what you mean about the furthest one being returned though

Comment: I answered this at 2 am and can't honestly remember my train of thought. Sorry about that. Hope I didn't confuse you to much though.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the other answers, your issue is that you're having different `count` variables, one for each recursive call. Incrementing one won't change the others. Instead of passing a (non const) reference you can also go for a more functional programming approach and return the count from your function. Of course you then need to *sum up* the returned counts of all recursive calls you made:

```
unsigned recursiveCount(Node const * node) /* you don't change the node, so make
                                              it const. Why a pointer btw? A
                                              reference would do fine! */
{
    unsigned count = 0; /* You aren't expecting a negative number of
                           words, are you? So use unsigned. */
    if (node->value == '$')
    {
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (node->array[i] != NULL) /* "array"!? change that to a meaningful
                                       name ... "children" is bad, but not as
                                       bad as "array" ... */
        {
            count += recursiveCount(node->array[i]); /* "arr" was a typo I
                                                        suppose */
        }
    }
    return count; /* consistent indentation, please! */
}
```

Comment: This method seemed a lot more logical than the way I was going about it but for some reason it is still returning a 1.

Comment: @Chris Might be an issue with your tree? What input are you giving to this function, and what output do you expect?

Comment: I've tested the tree very thoroughly. The insert and find methods work flawlessly. In the function that calls the recursive function, first I declare a temp pointer and have it point at the root. When I call the function, I just do "return recursiveCount(temp);"

Comment: Whoops I'm sorry, 1 is actually the correct return value. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris :) You're welcome. Don't forget to build up a good habit and keep those tests you were probably running this function against as unit tests.

Comment: Yes I will be sure to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this as C++, so I'm puzzled why the method is not part of Node.  See encapsulation.

The significant error in your recursion code is not *adding* every '$'s found in each subsequent node.  In particular, your code returns the count of only one invocation of the for loop, all others are discarded.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
{
    if (temp->array[i] != NULL)
    {
        return recursiveCount(temp->arr[i],count);
        // This only returns one value,
        // and ignores all the other 26 possible values
        // these should sum together
    }
}
```

Consider making the method part of the node.  Note how retVal accumulates every '$' found.

```
int Node::recursiveCount()
{
    int retVal = 0; // accumulation

    if (value == '$') 
    { 
        retVal += 1;  // 1 word found here
    }

    // keep searching here, there might still be words with prefix
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (nullptr != nxt[i]) 
        {
            retVal += (nxt[i]->recursiveCount());
            //     ^^ accumulate any other words found
        }
    }
    return (retVal); // return full count
}
```

Comment: not compiled, not unit tested, please submit [MCVE]